# send list from c# to Oracle for batch processing

Tags: c#, oracle

tl;dr - can you send a number of "records" to oracle, as opposed to sending a single record many times?

Detail - I have data coming back from a SOAP call that needs adding to Oracle. It comes back as one big string, like so:
    aaa36dbe4e25|C01^67f1843664a8|R02^1ed490827c2a|C05^e68fd1e98380|R08^9a819553d3df|R08^d41c89cadcee|R01^aaa36dbe4e25|R02^6844d9bd616c|R03^bf33b46ea251|C02^

Each record is the pair split by the pipe, records separated by the caret.

Now, I can just send that ugly string the Oracle as a clob, and let Oracle handle splitting it up and processing. That's certainly the least amount of work on my side.

But is there some structure I can build on the C# side - a list, a 2D array, what have you - that I can pass as some parameter type that Oracle will then be able to use directly?

I've seen questions about trying to pass it as a refcursor, but they said that it'd have to come FROM oracle AS a cursor, so that ain't it.

Answer (score 1):

ODP.NET allows you to bind arrays. Article linked below shows how. Key points:

Create Array with values

```
string[] job_id_vals = new string[3] { "IT_DBA",
                "IT_MAN",
                "IT_VP" };
```

Create parameter, assign it the array we just created:

```
OracleParameter p_job_id = new OracleParameter();
p_job_id.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
p_job_id.Value = job_id_vals;
```

Set the number of items in the array(s) and add the parameter to the command:

```
cmd.ArrayBindCount = job_id_vals.Length;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p_job_id);
```

https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/put-your-arrays-in-a-bind

That works if you're not going through a stored procedure. If you want to do the same thing via a packaged stored procedure, it is a little more complicated - you use associated arrays. Again, from an article:

Package Body / Spec - note you have to declare the table types and the insert happens via a loop.

```
create or replace package associative_array as
  -- define an associative array type for each column in the jobs table
  type t_job_id is table of jobs.job_id%type index by pls_integer;
  type t_job_title is table of jobs.job_title%type index by pls_integer;
  type t_min_salary is table of jobs.min_salary%type index by pls_integer;
  type t_max_salary is table of jobs.max_salary%type index by pls_integer;
  -- define the procedure that will perform the array insert
  procedure array_insert (p_job_id in t_job_id,
                                   p_job_title in t_job_title,
                                   p_min_salary in t_min_salary,
                                   p_max_salary in t_max_salary);
end associative_array;
/
create or replace package body associative_array as
  -- implement the procedure that will perform the array insert
  procedure array_insert (p_job_id in t_job_id,
                                   p_job_title in t_job_title,
                                   p_min_salary in t_min_salary,
                                   p_max_salary in t_max_salary) is
  begin
    forall i in p_job_id.first..p_job_id.last
    insert into jobs (job_id,
                           job_title,
                           min_salary,
                           max_salary)
              values (p_job_id(i),
                         p_job_title(i),
                         p_min_salary(i),
                         p_max_salary(i));
  end array_insert;
end associative_array;
```

The C# is pretty standard and similar to the array bind method. But there is one key difference - you set the size on each parameter rather than the array size on the command. The arrays could be different sizes when you go this route:

```
p_job_id.Size = 3;
```

https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/using-plsql-associative-arrays

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20649007)

Comment: Good point - edited to add the key steps as listed in the article.